# Unable to map SQL Query Response to C# variables

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have this SQL Query Script which I am trying to invoke through ADO.Net code.

```
DECLARE   
  @Error NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE
  @Errors TABLE
  (
    [Column_Name] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Message] VARCHAR(MAX)
  )

IF NOT EXISTS(...)  
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO @Errors
  SELECT
    'Col1',
    'value does not exist.'
END

IF NOT EXISTS(...)  
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO @Errors
  SELECT
    'Col2',
    'value does not exist.'
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Errors)
BEGIN 
  SET @Error = (  
    SELECT  
      [Column_Name],
      [Message]
    FROM
      @Errors
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
  );

  SELECT @Error AS 'Error_Message'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) Id
    FROM dbo.table
END
```

This is the C# code

```
using (var conn = await _connectionFactory.OpenConnectionAsync(database: "dbName", readOnly: true))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommandFromSqlFile(path, "test.sql"))
    {
        string errors = string.Empty;
        Guid id;

        using (DataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct))
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync(ct))
                {
                    errors = reader.GetString("Error_Message");
                    id = reader.GetGuid("Id");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The SQL Script always returns either, `Error_Message` or `Id` based on the condition. If `@Errors` table is populated, it returns `Error_Message` and if there are no errors then it returns the `Id`.

I am trying to get these values in the c# code but it throws an exception in the `while` block, since one of the values, either `Error_Message` or `Id` will not be present.

I need help in getting these values gracefully to my C# code. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Use output parameters.

Comment: @DaleK - The SQL script is not a stored procedure or a function, it is just a plain SQL script.

Comment: So? You can use parameters with plain SQL... I use them all the time for a small number of return values they perform better because you don't need readers and/or DataTables etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a "graceful" way to do it the way you're structuring it IMHO

- you could use a c# try catch, to catch the exception that occurs when error is not present, but exception handling is slooow and shouldn't be used as a normal flow of control device
- you could change your queries so that they both return the same column names so there aren't any more exceptions, and the id is represented as a string and you either have another column to direct you as to whether the string is a GUId or an error so you can parse or report it appropriately, or you try and parse it and see if it works
- you could change your queries so they always have two columns- a string and a GUId and one is always null, and use the null to determine which type of thing you have
- you could always select both your errors and your ids and leverage the fact that sql server allows you to have multiple result sets open

But realistically I think I'd stop trying to return SQL errors as resultsets and just [throw them as exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and catch them in c#. Adopt a pattern of having a string that starts off blank, check for col1 and if it's not there append "col1 doesn't exist" to the string, check for col2 and maybe append "col2 doesn't exist".. then if the string isn't blank THROW it, otherwise return your resultset. C# will experience an exception with a useful error message (and you can provide a variable code if you want to handle it differently rather than just report to the user)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetName` function of the `SqlDataReader`

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct))
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (await reader.ReadAsync(ct))
        {
            var colName = reader.GetName(0);
            if (colName.Equals("Error_Message")
                errors = reader.GetString("Error_Message");
            else 
                id = reader.GetGuid("Id");
        }
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetName_System_Int32_